# how to custom XHR (XMLHttpRequest) packet size in polling request?

Tags: configuration, odoo, xmlhttprequest, size, packet

When a poll request is sent to the server, I have noticed that several XHR packets are sent to the server with a maximum size of 500 KB. In some cases, the procedure can be very lengthy and risky, especially if a server connection issue occurs. For that, I thought about finding a way to configure the packet size if it's possible.